# Why does undefined Generics types of Collections defaults to Object even if bound to other class?

Tags: java, generics, generic-list

```
class Test<G extends String>{
    public G test(){return null;}
    public List<G> tests(){return new ArrayList<>();}
}
public void doTest(Test t){
    //works fine
    String str = t.test();
    //Compile error: expected String found Object
    str = t.tests().iterator().next();
}
```

I would like the last line to return a String instance instead of Object, as the type G was bound to subclass String. There is any other way than casting ?

Comment: Because with raw types the generic bound you defined is never considered in the first place, as if you never genericized your class at all. This is partially because before Java 1.5 generics didn't exist in Java, and there wouldn't be a way to implement the behavior you describe.

Comment: In this case shouldn't t.test() return Object too ?

Comment: Hmmm... Interesting point. Missed that at first. I suppose in this case it'd be because the returned `ArrayList` would be a raw type then. Not entirely sure why `t.test()` would return a `String`.

Comment: `G extends String` Is there any meaning of this type of generic. `String` is immutable final class. In that case simply use `Test<String>`. Try `new ArrayList<G>()`

Comment: I used String just for demonstration, the same happens with other classes. I will update the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the type as been erased. You're running into two different rules for type erasure - from [JLS section 4.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6):

> - The erasure of a parameterized type (§4.5) G is |G|.
> - The erasure of a type variable (§4.4) is the erasure of its leftmost bound.

So the erasure of `List<G>` is `List`, but the erasure of `G` is `String` - that's why the first assignment works.

All you need to do to get this code to compile is use a wildcard in your parameter:

```
public void doTest(Test<?> t)
```

Comment: Hmmm, just curious -- what does a return type of `?` mean for `next()`? Would that result in a runtime exception if the types don't work out? Or is it safe because `G` is always `String`?

Comment: @user3580294: It's safe because `G` is always assignment-compatible with `String`... basically you've got an `Iterator<? extends String>` to call `next()` on.

Comment: Strangely enough, Eclipse is telling me that `iterator()` returns an `Iterator<?>`, which I'm a little confused about, but your response makes sense.

Comment: @user3580294: You might want to try `Test<? extends String> t` and see if that changes Eclipse. It seems to be okay in javac - although that's with JDK 8, and things might have changed since JDK 7...

Comment: Oh, sorry for not being more clear; it compiles both ways, it's just that initially, the tooltip when hovering over `iterator()` showed that it returned `Iterator<?>`. Changing the parameter declaration indeed changes the indicated return type.