# How is a generic list type erased? When I try it myself, it gives an error

Tags: java, generics

I tried to figure out how the following method is type erased

```
public class Util {
    public static <T extends Number> int sum(List<T>list){
        int sum=0;
        for(Number n:list){
            sum+=n.intValue();
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

I read that type parameters are replaced with its first bound.
So I tried that, but got an error:

```
public static int sum3(List list){
    int sum=0; 
    for(Number n:list){         <- Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to Number
        sum+=n.intValue();
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: @Tunaki that dupe really isn't answering OP's question at all.

Comment: @Andy Isn't it the same issue, with using a raw list in a for-each loop? In the linked question, they have `for (String s : perms) {` where `perms` is a `List`, which is also what the OP has here.

Comment: @Tunaki but OP is specifically asking "how the following method is type erased". The dupe says basically "don't use raw types" - which is, of course, good advice - but not providing what OP apparently wants to know.

Comment: @Andy OK I see what you mean. I found [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388034/what-will-be-the-runtime-signature) instead (maybe [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24171300/why-does-undefined-generics-types-of-collections-defaults-to-object-even-if-boun)). Feel free to reclose if you think they fully answer this one.

Comment: @Tunaki no to both - the first one is simply about method signature (OP is asking about method body too); second one is simply asking why raw collections iterate as objects (which is basically the same as your previous dupe). I think OP is asking about how to write the equivalent type-erased code to his method - see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second code isn't actually the equivalent code after type erasure. It can't be, because, as you've found, the enhanced for loop wouldn't compile.

If you consult the [language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2), it shows the equivalent basic for loop for the enhanced for loop:

```
for (I #i = Expression.iterator(); #i.hasNext(); ) {
    {VariableModifier} TargetType Identifier =
        (TargetType) #i.next();
    Statement
}
```

This is *actually* what gets executed: enhanced for loops are just syntactic sugar for a basic for loop which looks like this.

So, the first thing the compiler would do to your first code would be to "desugar" it to:

```
public static <T extends Number> int sum(List<T>list){
  int sum=0;
  for (Iterator<Number> i = list.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
    Number n = (Number) i.next();
    sum += n.intValue();
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Then, when it is time to apply type erasure, it would rewrite to:

```
public static int sum(List list){
  int sum=0;
  for (Iterator i = list.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
    Number n = (Number) i.next();
    sum += n.intValue();
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Notice that the only different here is that `i.next()` is a `Number` in the first case, thus making the cast unnecessary; but it is `Object` in the second (because of the raw iterator), so the cast is necessary.

This form of the type-erased code compiles. Indeed, if you try decompiling this version of the code, you will see that it has bytecode identical to the first code in the OP's question.

Of course, as Sotirios pointing out by marking the question a dupe of [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/3788176), you shouldn't attempt to do the type erasure yourself. But it is useful to know what it is doing.

Comment: It is  the Number cast I was missing, because of the foreach loop.

Comment: @ericj it is the syntactic desugaring that you were missing, *and then* the cast. You can't apply the cast with the enhanced for loop.

Comment: Yes, I understood that. Thank you very much.

Comment: I checked the bytecodes. Indeed, they are identical.

Answer (score 0):

Erasure happens after the compiler's type-checking phase. 
Ultimately, it will result in what you wrote, but the type checking is done first.

Comment: @ericj did you even read the answer? Keyword here is *ultimately*.